# Mixed effects model specification lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I am quite new to mixed effects modelling but am starting to explore more complex designs for hypothesis testing using `lmer` in R. The model specification is starting to get more complex and I am wondering if anyone could give an opinion on whether what I am doing is appropriate for the question at hand, or if they could point to a resource for understanding how to build up the statistical model.

I have a nested experimental design (cell biology) in which I measure approx. 1000 individuals (cells) in each group (well). Each well is either a treatment or control group. There are 3 wells for each treatment.

So far I have been testing for significant effects of treatment on the value measured for each cell using:

```r
lmer(formula = value ~ treatment + (1 | well), data = .)
```

which I think treats `well` as a random effect and allows me to test (using `anova`) whether the fixed effect `treatment` significantly affects `value` in the context of this nested design (with multiple wells for each treatment). Based on some simulations this seems to give the expected results.

Now I want to extend this to compare measurements taken within different parts (compartments) of each cell and ask the question: *"does the treatment have different effects on the different compartments in the cell?"*. My first attempt at this was:

```r
lmer(formula = value ~ treatment + compartment + 
     treatment:compartment + (1 | well), data = .)
```

where the `values` are now measured in two different compartments for each cell. I then used `anova` to look at the significance of the interaction term `treatment:compartment`

This gives for example,

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                       Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
treatment              0.5598  0.5598     1    6.1   24.94  0.002396 ** 
compartment            9.8343  9.8343     1 8860.0  438.15 < 2.2e-16 ***
treatment:compartment 18.0228 18.0228     1 8860.0  802.98 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

which I think means that `treatment` and `condition` (both two-level factors) have a significant effect on `value` and that *the effect is different for the two compartments* (based on significance of `treatment:compartment`).

Two questions:

1. Do I need to also specify any additional random effects after including the additional fixed effects in the model?
2. Does it matter that the two compartments come from the same cell (i.e. these are not strictly independent)? I have unique labels for each cell.

Comment: `(1 | well) + (1 | well:treatment)` suggests that `treatment` is nested in `well` which doesn't seem to be the case here.  Also, as a gneral rule you don't want to include a fixed effect as part of a grouping term for random effects, unless you have a very good reason. You say "*each group (well), which is either a treatment or control group*" which tells me that `well` indicates the treatment group, but in that case what is the `treatment` variable for ? Please can you explain your study design and data clearly ?

Comment: Hi @RobertLong thanks for the input, you have helped already. Sorry if this is confusing. There are multiple wells for each treatment, so "well is nested in treatment", correct? I have edited the question to remove the `well:treatment` terms, (they were only necessary when I had replicated well labels in the two treatment groups for my simulated data).

Comment: "*There are multiple wells for each treatment, so "well is nested in treatment", correct?*" If each level of `well` belongs to one and only one level of `treatment` then yes, although it's largely irrelevant since with only 2 treatments, and with treatment as your main exposure, it would not make sense to fit nested random effects.